# Close issue on GitHub pull request to non master branch

Tags: git, github

I am aware of how to close an issue using a pull request message.
But that only happens if the destination branch is master.

What if i want to close an issue while merging to a non master branch?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, it isn't important whether you push to  `master` or some other branch. What matters is that you push to the *default branch*, which defaults to `master` but [can be changed](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/) if you have repository admin rights.

Pushing to non-default branches [does not close issues](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/#closing-an-issue-in-the-same-repository):

> If the commit is in a non-default branch, the issue will remain open and the issue will be referenced with a tooltip.

It should be possible to build something to automatically close issues based on commits to multiple branches using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), but out of the box you're out of luck.